# Why am I getting error: ‘viewModel’ is a variable but is used like a ‘method’?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I created a view model of all lists

```
 namespace XXX.ViewModels
  {
     public class AlertData
     {

    public virtual List<String> lstPresent { get; set; }
    public virtual List<String> lstTardy { get; set; }
    public virtual List<String> lstNoShow { get; set; }
     }
 }
```

Then in my controller I want to do something like this:

```
  private List<XXX.ViewModels.AlertData> dataToBeReturned()
    {
```

…code to load lists here…

Then I create a view model and assigned new data to it:

```
        var viewModel=new AlertData();
        viewModel.lstPresent=present;
        viewModel.lstTardy=tardy;
        viewModel. lstNoShow = nowShow;
```

Finally I want to return like this:

```
 Return viewModel();
```

It is here that I get an error message that says ‘viewModel’ is a variable but is used like a ‘method’.  I searched but could not find a problem quite like mine.

Why am I getting error: ‘viewModel’ is a variable but is used like a ‘method’?

Thanks for any help with this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The viewModel that you're returning on the last line *is* actually a variable (an object that you instantiated), so you can simply return it without the parenthesis:

```
return viewModel;
```

Comment: Got it!  Thanks guys!!!  Sorry I can't check answer for each of you but you were all correct.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Because `viewModel` is a variable. You're using it like a method.

When you call a method.. you pass arguments in parenthesis, like this:

```
someMethod(arg1, arg2);
```

You're trying to do that.. with your `viewModel` variable:

```
viewModel();
```

This is incorrect. Just return the view model:

```
return viewModel;
//             ^^ no parenthesis
```

Comment: Removed the parenthesis and now getting:  Cannot implicitly  convert type ‘XXX.ViewModels.AlertData to System.Collections.Generic.List<XXX.ViewModels.AlertData>.

Comment: Because your method wants to return a list.. you are returning a single item.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the parenthesis:

```
return viewModel;
```

When you include the parentheses, it thinks you're trying to return the result of a method called `viewModel()`, which doesn't exist.